# JavaScript: Append text to h1 from an array with for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner with JavaScript and don't know how to solve this simple issue.
I want to add text in h2 from an array with for loop

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  const titles = ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 3"];
  for (let i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        var addText = "<h2>";
        addText += titles[i];
        addText += "</h2>";
    $(".ic-table-h2").append(addText);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="ic-table-h2"></div>
 <div class="ic-table-h2"></div>
 <div class="ic-table-h2"></div>
 <div class="ic-table-h2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what's the problem with what you have?

Comment: I am assuming you want to insert each array value in its own div?  
Like this should be the output you want in your HTML? 
 <div class="ic-table-h2">Title 1</div>
 <div class="ic-table-h2">Title 2</div>
 <div class="ic-table-h2">Title 3</div>
 <div class="ic-table-h2">Title 3</div>

Comment: @DanielResch Yes, that's correct! I want to do that, but don't know how.

Comment: @420reefermad why was Haim Abeles answer below not OK for you then?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  const titles = ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 3"];
  for (let i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        var addText = "<h2>";
        addText += titles[i];
        addText += "</h2>";
    document.querySelectorAll(".ic-table-h2")[i].append(addText);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="ic-table-h2"></div>
 <div class="ic-table-h2"></div>
 <div class="ic-table-h2"></div>
 <div class="ic-table-h2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! You really helped me solve this issue. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if I understood your problem correctly, but I would solve your problem like this (rebuilding the entire html inside your container, because this way you are flexible with your array size):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  const titles = ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 3"];

  var html = ''; 
  for (let i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        html += "<div class='ic-table-h2'><h2>"+titles[i]+"</h2></div>"; 
  };

  $(".container").html(html); 

});
```

You could then simplify your html to just like this:

```
<div class="container">
</div>
```

would give you this output in HTML:

```
<div class="container"><div class="ic-table-h2"><h2>Title 1</h2></div><div class="ic-table-h2"><h2>Title 2</h2></div><div class="ic-table-h2"><h2>Title 3</h2></div><div class="ic-table-h2"><h2>Title 3</h2></div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much time and help. Yes @Haim Abeles helped me with this issue, and your solution is helpful too! Thanks again, cheers mate :)